# Simultaneous Updates in both client sides

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, sockets, flask

I wanted to create a lobby based webpage, where clients would enter a room code to enter a specific room. I was wondering how I would then be able to update the view in the room simultaneously to make the user would just joined and other users who are currently in the room to see the new added user.

I wasn't what kind of keyword I should search for at all. I am currently using React as my frontend, with flask and MongoDB at the backend. I know that with MongoDB you can use some sort of even listener, but I was wondering if this is the standard way to do this, or is there some sort of socket programming that is more appropriate.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Socket.IO in conjunction with React and Flask. React has socket.io/client from npm while Flask has a Flask socketio library.